# Memory Issue Preventing Input into Struct?

Tags: c, input, struct, scanf

I don't understand why the last line asking for user weight input is not executed. Could it be a memory issue? Or have I written the structs incorrectly? Or have I written the calls to scanf() incorrectly? Or all the above?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct date{
  int month;
  int day;
  int year;
};

struct healthProfile{
  char firstName[20];
  char lastName[20];
  struct date birthday;
  float height; //inches
  float weight; //pounds
};



int main(void)
{
  struct healthProfile patient1;

  printf("%s\t", "Please enter the patient's first name:");
  scanf("%s", patient1.firstName);


  printf("%s\t", "Please enter the patient's last name:");
  scanf("%s", patient1.lastName);

  printf("%s\t", "Please enter the date of birth(mm/dd/yyyy)");
  scanf("%2i/%2i/%4i", &patient1.birthday.month, &patient1.birthday.day, &patient1.birthday.year);

  printf("%s\t", "Please enter the patient's height in inches");
  scanf("%.2f", &patient1.height);

  printf("%s\t", "Please enter the patient's weight in pounds");
  scanf("%.2f", &patient1.weight);



  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you know it is not?

Comment: What exactly does the program do? Does it just exit normally, crash or something else?

Comment: Yes, it exits normally. I can input everything else, except the last line

Comment: Please clarify your question, you mean the the program doesn't wait for user input for the weight input.

Comment: use `%d` rather than `%i` in the scanf. Otherwise you will run into trouble if they write `09` for the birth month

Comment: Apart from the problem you are asking about, other problems include `scanf()` format specifiers do not take precision specifiers, `%f` takes `double` and `%i` process octal(zero prefixed), decimal, and hexadecimal (0x prefixed) input; your program will fail for two digit date values 08 or 09 as these are not valid octal values - use `%d` to force interpretation as decimal.

Comment: @Clifford `%f` format spec in `scanf` family takes `float`. The format for `double` is `%lf`. (`printf` is different).

Comment: @WeatherVane :. I stand corrected.

Comment: Given weight in pounds and height in inches, in what world would floating point be necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `printf`, a format specifier to `scanf` doesn't take a precision.  The compiler should warn you of this:

```
x1.c: In function ‘main’:
x1.c:34:3: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘.’ in format [-Wformat=]
   scanf("%.2f", &patient1.height);
   ^
x1.c:34:3: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
x1.c:37:3: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘.’ in format [-Wformat=]
   scanf("%.2f", &patient1.weight);
   ^
x1.c:37:3: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
```

Remove the precision and you'll be able to read properly:

```
printf("%s\t", "Please enter the patient's height in inches");
scanf("%f", &patient1.height);

printf("%s\t", "Please enter the patient's weight in pounds");
scanf("%f", &patient1.weight);
```

Comment: True, but not the cause of the problem being asked about.

Comment: also, the printfs should be flushed, since there's no linefeed. You could get "no input" because of this.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive input from the console, it is line buffered but the %f format specifier only extracts the numeric data, leaving the newline (at least) in the buffer.  The next input discards the leading white-space (the newline from the previous call), but for the last input you need or discard it.  One way:

```
  int c ;
  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
  scanf("%f", &patient1.weight);
```

It is however a good idea to do this after any input that does not consume a newline, and simpler to wrap the input in a function say `getfloat()` in this case to reduce repetition.